# Difference between zhongshu and zaishu and zhishu?

Tags: difference, word

大家好！

1.可以说种树，植树，栽树，为什么植树节只能说植树？

2.为什么说栽秧，种秧，而不说植秧？

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 植(as a verb used separately, when compared with used in compound verbs like 移植 种植) is somehow formal. Hence except for the idiomatic use of 植树, 植花 is rarely heard but 栽花 种花 is very common.

植物节 is a proper noun and using 种树节 or 栽树节 will make it sound informal.

植秧 seems to exist. However, the following example is from a written record. I have no idea whether 植秧 is commonly used in spoken Chinese.

> 从四月底开始，负责打理这块地的老王便有条不紊地除草、松土、灌水、育苗、植秧，让我这个长期以来没有离开过与土地打交道的人也不免常常走近他，问长问短，交流起种植的心得与体会。(吴棉国著. 定西，我初见的模样)

Nonetheless common use seems to be 插秧 or 栽秧. In fact, 插(insert) and 栽(plant) here refer to 'transplanting'. The way to grow rice is : first grow the seedlings in a nursery and then transplant them into fields. (http://www.knowledgebank.irri.org/training/fact-sheets/crop-establishment/manual-transplanting) 插 describes the action of inserting the seedling into the field. 移(to move)秧 is also acceptable. 种秧 seems to be a dialectal use.

Ancient Chinese used 莳秧 (according to 说文, 莳 means exactly 'to transplant'), which is still used in the Wu dialect.

Answer (score 1):

> 植树, 栽树

These terms are written words and sound very formal.

> 种树

This term can be used in both formal and colloquial ways. 种树节 would sound too colloquial, and is not proper for a special day's name.

For 栽秧 and 植树/种树, instead of 植秧, these are just idiomatic set phrases. There's no need to delve into the difference.